# ec2 document all traffic from machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy, web-traffic

I want to document all inbound and outbount traffic from an ec2 machine.
I want all to be kept on a log on the machine (or on an s3 bucket, nevermind...)
basiclly I need a log that sniffs all the traffic.
For example if I do a cURL command from the machine to another server I want the request and the response to be documented to a log.

Can you recommend which way is best to implement the requirements?
Currently, I don't know which direction should I follow and looking for guidance in implementing a solution

Thank you!

Comment: You say "All traffic inbound and outbound". Are you just referring to web traffic (eg ports 80/443), or is it everything (for example, including SSH, DNS, FTP, etc)?

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A, so your question might be closed. You might get a better response at: https://serverfault.com

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein I need all ports.
And also thanks for referring me to server fault, I didn't know this site.

Comment: [command line - How can I monitor all outgoing requests/connections from my machine? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56453/how-can-i-monitor-all-outgoing-requests-connections-from-my-machine)